# Acumatica - tstemp can not be empty

Tags: acumatica

We are getting "tstemp can not be empty" error when trying to update the production order items.

Production order is created and release and then trying to update the line items.

what could be the reason???

Comment: Are you working with custom DACs? Are you able to insert but not update?

Comment: We created the instance of the graph - ProdDetail
and trying to update multiple Dataviews in that graph and then call
graph.Save.Press()

this line generates the error

Comment: Could you post the applicable parts of that code (DAC and graph, etc)?

Comment: marking AMProdItem as on hold then, we are deleting some of AMProdMatl items, few are editing/inserting then i am calling Action.PressSave method then getting error. we do not have any custom properties in AMProdItem or AMProdMatl. but getting the tstemp can not be empty error. 
Before updating we are setting the ProdDetail.prodDetailMaint.ProdItemRecords.Current = AMProdItem then doing all operation.

Comment: In our case we are able to insert the new rows in AMProdMatlview but on Update of existing row, it ends up with the above error

Comment: That does sound very unusual. At this point though, this question really can't go anywhere. I don't think anyone will be able to help you without seeing code. I'm not sure anyone will be able to help you WITH code, but since it's StackOverflow, it's worth a shot.

Comment: finding the object 
AMProdOper prodOper = PXSelect<AMProdOper, Where<AMProdOper.orderType, Equal<Required<AMProdOper.orderType>>, And<AMProdOper.prodOrdID, Equal<Required<AMProdOper.prodOrdID>>, And<AMProdOper.operationID, Equal<Required<AMProdOper.operationID>>>>>, OrderBy<Asc<AMProdOper.operationID>>>.Select(this, new object[] { amProdItem.OrderType, amProdItem.ProdOrdID, AMProdOperID });  
then assing some value and call ProdDetail operation dataview update method then at the end call Action.Save then getting tstemp error.

Comment: we have multiple operation, each operation may have multiple Material, Overhead, Tools edit/delete or insert, operation it self can be added. so we are looping some of our record and accordingly we find the operation exist, if Operation exist the we edit and set the operation as current and then loop through material and processing similar to  operation, if exist then edit else insert. then getting the tstemp error. any idea?

Comment: For future reference, it's very helpful to have the code in the original post, as it can then be formatted, etc. For instance, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66225141/why-does-the-rowselected-event-not-fire-on-records-imported-through-import-scena

Does the select statement function correctly? I've never seen ``Select(this, new object[] {  })`` before. I've always seen and used ``Select(this, amProdItem.OrderType, amProdItem.ProdOrdID, AMProdOperID)``. It could be a completely valid function, just not one I'm familiar with.

Comment: Error seems Random to me, any update (add/Update/Delete)  gives this error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tsTemp error is displayed when the Record in the Dataview.Update is called where as that record does not exists in that DataView.